# Date formatting issue for report

Tags: r

I have a date of birth 7/9/2018 in one file and the other file has 07/09/2018 in an other file for the same person.

I cannot use the R format for date in my final report. it has to be in mm/dd/yyyy format(excel format).

Is it possible to add 0 to the date if the number of digits in a month or date is 1 by creating a function in R studio.

Comment: Dates in R are printed as yyyy-mm-dd. The values above indicate that your variables are not stored as dates. See `?as.Date` to convert variables to dates. There are loads of questions about this. Once you have performed the date conversion, you can use `print` together with the format argument to get it to print how you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using base R

```
x <- "7/9/2018"

#convert to date
x <- as.Date(x, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
x
#[1] "2018-07-09"

#convert back to character in desired format
x2 <- format(x, "%m/%d/%Y")
x2
#[1] "07/09/2018"
```

see `?strptime` for format conversion specifications.